# Проблема с запуском gulp. Выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе

Tags: gulp, npm

При запуске gulp выдает ошибку которая показана на скриншоте. Сам gulp установлен как локально, так и глобально.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался куда проще чем я думал.
В PowerShell нужно было написать команду Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned.
Затем ответить A(да, для всех)